# Can't reduce whitespaces, remove accent, and replace words in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have the following data frame :

```r
structure(list(matching_var = c("BD Mymensingh", "CN Nei Mongol ", "EC Los Ríos", "MY  Johor", "MY  Kedah", "MY  Kelantan", "MY Negeri Sembilan", "RU Amurskaja oblast")), row.names = c(44L,174L, 259L, 694L, 695L, 696L, 700L, 1029L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like it to become :

```r
structure(list(matching_var = c("BD Mymensingh", "CN Nei Mongol", "EC Los Rios", "MY Johor", "MY Kedah", "MY Kelantan", "MY Negeri Sembilan", "RU Amur")), row.names = c(44L, 174L, 259L, 694L, 695L, 696L, 700L, 1029L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried the following code, but it does not work :

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(matching_var = str_replace(matching_var, "MY  Johor", "MY Johor")) %>% 
  mutate(matching_var = str_replace(matching_var, "Los Ríos", "Los Rios"))%>% 
  mutate(matching_var = str_replace(matching_var, "MY  Kedah", "MY Kedah"))%>% 
  mutate(matching_var = str_replace(matching_var, "MY  Kelantan", "MY Kelantan "))%>% 
  mutate(matching_var = str_replace(matching_var, "Amurskaja oblast", "Amur"))
```

I Also tried this for whitespaces but still nothing :

```r
data$matching_var <-str_replace_all(data$matching_var, fixed("  "), " ")
```

The output looks exactly like the input, I can't figure out why. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're going to do replacement with fixed strings, one option is to `merge`/`left_join` a conversion table:

   ```r
   conversions <- tribble(
   ~fm,               ~ to,
   "MY  Johor"        , "MY Johor",
   "Los Ríos"         , "Los Rios",
   "MY  Kedah"        , "MY Kedah",
   "MY  Kelantan"     , "MY Kelantan ",
   "Amurskaja oblast" , "Amur")

   left_join(data, conversions, by = c("matching_var" = "fm")) %>%
     mutate(
       new_matching_var = coalesce(to, matching_var)
     ) %>%
     select(-to)
   #          matching_var    new_matching_var
   # 1       BD Mymensingh       BD Mymensingh
   # 2      CN Nei Mongol       CN Nei Mongol 
   # 3         EC Los Ríos         EC Los Ríos
   # 4           MY  Johor            MY Johor
   # 5           MY  Kedah            MY Kedah
   # 6        MY  Kelantan        MY Kelantan 
   # 7  MY Negeri Sembilan  MY Negeri Sembilan
   # 8 RU Amurskaja oblast RU Amurskaja oblast
   ```

   (Note that the `"MY Kelantan "` has a trailing space that you added to your own code.)
2. Another option is to use `conversions` and `match`, without the merge/join:

   ```r
   data %>%
     mutate(
       ind = match(matching_var, conversions$fm), 
       new_matching_var = if_else(is.na(ind), 
       matching_var, conversions$to[ind])
     ) %>%
     select(-ind)
   #             matching_var    new_matching_var
   # 44         BD Mymensingh       BD Mymensingh
   # 174       CN Nei Mongol       CN Nei Mongol 
   # 259          EC Los Ríos         EC Los Ríos
   # 694            MY  Johor            MY Johor
   # 695            MY  Kedah            MY Kedah
   # 696         MY  Kelantan        MY Kelantan 
   # 700   MY Negeri Sembilan  MY Negeri Sembilan
   # 1029 RU Amurskaja oblast RU Amurskaja oblast
   ```

   While this can be done with a named vector, one reason I recommend this is that it is easily maintained (e.g., as a CSV in a directory; you can use Excel or Calc to edit/maintain the list of conversions you want).
3. For the blank-space removal, one can use `trimws` to remove extra spaces from the beginning or end of the strings. I'll continue

   ```r
   data %>%
     mutate(
       ind = match(matching_var, conversions$fm), 
       new_matching_var = if_else(is.na(ind), 
       matching_var, conversions$to[ind])
     ) %>%
     select(-ind) %>%
     mutate(new_matching_var2 = trimws(new_matching_var))
   #             matching_var    new_matching_var   new_matching_var2
   # 44         BD Mymensingh       BD Mymensingh       BD Mymensingh
   # 174       CN Nei Mongol       CN Nei Mongol        CN Nei Mongol
   # 259          EC Los Ríos         EC Los Ríos         EC Los Ríos
   # 694            MY  Johor            MY Johor            MY Johor
   # 695            MY  Kedah            MY Kedah            MY Kedah
   # 696         MY  Kelantan        MY Kelantan          MY Kelantan
   # 700   MY Negeri Sembilan  MY Negeri Sembilan  MY Negeri Sembilan
   # 1029 RU Amurskaja oblast RU Amurskaja oblast RU Amurskaja oblast
   ```

   though I don't know what didn't work with `str_replace_all(data$matching_var, fixed("  "), " ")`, that *did* remove all of the literal mid-string `"  "` that I saw (well, at this point, there are no double-spaces remaining, but it would have).

You can replace all of that perhaps with a simpler two-step cleanup, assuming that you don't need to otherwise change values:

```r
data %>%
  mutate(
    new_matching_var = trimws(str_replace(matching_var, fixed("  "), " "))
  )
#             matching_var    new_matching_var
# 44         BD Mymensingh       BD Mymensingh
# 174       CN Nei Mongol        CN Nei Mongol
# 259          EC Los Ríos         EC Los Ríos
# 694            MY  Johor            MY Johor
# 695            MY  Kedah            MY Kedah
# 696         MY  Kelantan         MY Kelantan
# 700   MY Negeri Sembilan  MY Negeri Sembilan
# 1029 RU Amurskaja oblast RU Amurskaja oblast
```